# Fetching data from xmlhttp.responseText into excel

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I am writing a macro to fetch some data from website. I got struck in the following step. I want to take data part and print it in excel. I provided below the data structure and code I used to print data. I am trying various methods for three days. No luck!

```
"data": [{
 "annualisedVolatility": "37.35",
 "bestBuy": "6.04",.
  etc                               
 }]
```

VBA Code: I put URL with data; hence you can remove variable while testing

```
Sub getNSEFutData()
    ExpiryDate = Range("TSys_ExpiryDate")
    xRow = 4
    Do Until wksNSE50.Cells(xRow, 1) = ""
    scripID = wksNSE50.Cells(xRow, 1).Value
    scripID = Replace(scripID, "&", "%26")
    'URL = "http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=" & scripID & "&instrument=FUTSTK&expiry=" & ExpiryDate
    URL = "http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=ADANIPORTS&instrument=FUTSTK&expiry=25OCT2018"
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", URL, False
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/JSON"
    xmlhttp.Send
    sNo = InStr(1, xmlhttp.responseText, "id=" & Chr(34) & "responseDiv")
    Debug.Print xmlhttp.responseText
    Dim jsonStr As String
    jsonStr = Trim(Mid(xmlhttp.responseText, sNo, InStr(sNo, xmlhttp.responseText, "/div>") - sNo))
    Debug.Print jsonStr

    xRow = xRow + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Use a library to parse the JSON.  E.g. https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried with github, I am getting error since the out put data comes in between many other line. I don't know how to store data part alone and then do the parsing. Will you check the actual output I get at last?

Comment: Why is the HTTP request inside the loop? Nothing seems to change in relation to this during the loop.

Comment: @QHarr I will loop through the list of stock, I provided here just an example of one stock code, I am able to get data in between multiple HTTP output, I want to print data with in the range I specified in the question, Any help..pls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is using [JSONConvertor.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) and the whole JSON string (not just from Data). You would just adjust your current InStr method of determining the JSON extraction start and end points. I am reading in from a cell. "Data" is a collection. The first item is a dictionary which contains the values you are after. You simply loop the keys of the dictionary as shown below. It is easy enough to write these to a row, for example, by adding a cell reference using `Cells` with rowCounter and columnCounter variables to position. You would have the rowCounter increment in your outer loop to write to a new row each time.

**VBA:**

```
Public Sub GetInfoFromSheet()
    Dim jsonStr As String, json As Object, key As Variant, columnCounter As Long, rowCounter As Long
    jsonStr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").[a1]
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonStr)("data")(1)
    rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
    For Each key In json
        columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").cells(rowCounter, columnCounter) = key & " : " & json(key)
    Next
End Sub
```

---

**JSON treeview:**

Here is a view of the path being traversed:

[image]

---

**JSON string:**

This is the JSON I am using:

```
{
  "valid": "true",
  "tradedDate": "28SEP2018",
  "eqLink": "/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=ADANIPORTS",
  "data": [
    {
      "annualisedVolatility": "37.35",
      "bestBuy": "8.22",
      "totalSellQuantity": "6,65,000",
      "vwap": "338.01",
      "clientWisePositionLimits": "7807220",
      "optionType": "-",
      "highPrice": "342.35",
      "dailyVolatility": "1.95",
      "bestSell": "9.22",
      "marketLot": "2500",
      "sellQuantity5": "7,500",
      "marketWidePositionLimits": "156144401",
      "sellQuantity4": "2,500",
      "sellQuantity3": "2,500",
      "sellQuantity2": "2,500",
      "underlying": "ADANIPORTS",
      "sellQuantity1": "5,000",
      "pChange": "0.55",
      "premiumTurnover": "-",
      "totalBuyQuantity": "4,95,000",
      "turnoverinRsLakhs": "15,227.35",
      "changeinOpenInterest": "3,35,000",
      "strikePrice": "-",
      "openInterest": "98,67,500",
      "buyPrice2": "338.10",
      "buyPrice1": "338.25",
      "openPrice": "339.80",
      "prevClose": "336.55",
      "expiryDate": "25OCT2018",
      "lowPrice": "333.75",
      "buyPrice4": "338.00",
      "buyPrice3": "338.05",
      "buyPrice5": "337.95",
      "numberOfContractsTraded": "1,802",
      "instrumentType": "FUTSTK",
      "sellPrice1": "338.50",
      "sellPrice2": "338.55",
      "sellPrice3": "338.70",
      "sellPrice4": "338.75",
      "sellPrice5": "338.80",
      "change": "1.85",
      "pchangeinOpenInterest": "3.51",
      "ltp": "8.82",
      "impliedVolatility": "-",
      "underlyingValue": "336.20",
      "buyQuantity4": "7,500",
      "buyQuantity3": "2,500",
      "buyQuantity2": "5,000",
      "buyQuantity1": "2,500",
      "buyQuantity5": "5,000",
      "settlementPrice": "336.55",
      "closePrice": "0.00",
      "lastPrice": "338.40"
    }
  ],
  "companyName": "Adani Ports and Special Economic Zone Limited",
  "lastUpdateTime": "28-SEP-2018 11:41:23",
  "isinCode": null,
  "ocLink": "/marketinfo/sym_map/symbolMapping.jsp?symbol=ADANIPORTS&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2"
}
```

---

Note:

If you just want to extract the Data part, not the longer string, then consider adjusting your current Instr method to retrieve the following valid JSON string:

```
[{"annualisedVolatility":"37.35","bestBuy":"6.01","totalSellQuantity":"6,30,000","vwap":"337.78","clientWisePositionLimits":"7807220","optionType":"-","highPrice":"342.35","dailyVolatility":"1.95","bestSell":"7.80","marketLot":"2500","sellQuantity5":"2,500","marketWidePositionLimits":"156144401","sellQuantity4":"7,500","sellQuantity3":"2,500","sellQuantity2":"2,500","underlying":"ADANIPORTS","sellQuantity1":"2,500","pChange":"0.65","premiumTurnover":"-","totalBuyQuantity":"6,20,000","turnoverinRsLakhs":"24,370.83","changeinOpenInterest":"5,15,000","strikePrice":"-","openInterest":"1,00,47,500","buyPrice2":"338.30","buyPrice1":"338.35","openPrice":"339.80","prevClose":"336.55","expiryDate":"25OCT2018","lowPrice":"333.75","buyPrice4":"338.10","buyPrice3":"338.20","buyPrice5":"338.05","numberOfContractsTraded":"2,886","instrumentType":"FUTSTK","sellPrice1":"338.80","sellPrice2":"338.90","sellPrice3":"338.95","sellPrice4":"339.00","sellPrice5":"339.05","change":"2.20","pchangeinOpenInterest":"5.40","ltp":"7.60","impliedVolatility":"-","underlyingValue":"336.85","buyQuantity4":"7,500","buyQuantity3":"2,500","buyQuantity2":"5,000","buyQuantity1":"2,500","buyQuantity5":"5,000","settlementPrice":"336.55","closePrice":"0.00","lastPrice":"338.75"}]
```

Comment: Good evening...   there are several ways to skin a cat.  I haven't seen that treeview before+

Answer (score 4):

I'm not clear on whether you're having trouble pulling the data in the first place, or just extracting the part you need.

In the URL you provided, I don't see any data like your example.  (The phrase `bestBuy` doesn't exist, and I see numbers like "337..." but not "37...".)

Regardless, if your issue is in getting data from the URL provided into Excel, it's easiest to use built-in functionality instead of re-writing existing features.

---

## 'Get External Data'

Go to the `Data` tab in Excel and click [`From Web`](https://www.octoparse.com/blog/scraping-data-from-website-to-excel).  When prompted, enter the [URL](http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=ADANIPORTS&instrument=FUTSTK&expiry=25OCT2018) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Results will vary depending on which page you're loading, but in this case I clicked `Table 0` in the left pane, and then clicked <kbd>Load</kbd>:

[image: img]

...then Excel loaded the data neatly into a table, which can be updated/refreshed automatically when required, or manually with only a click.

[image: img]

---

## `getHTTP`

If there's a reason you need to do this with VBA, that can also be done although will take some extra work one way or another.

For loading [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [HTML](https://wikipedia.org/HTML) from any site I use this function:

```
Public Function getHTTP(ByVal sReq As String) As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", sReq, False
        .Send
        getHTTP = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
End Function
```

---

### Example Usage:

As I'm not sure where you're getting your [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) data from, here's an example that displays Stack Overflow's [site status](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info), using the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/):

```
Sub GetSiteInfo()
    Const url = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=stackoverflow"
    Dim json As String

    json = getHTTP(url) 'get JSON response

    If InStr(json, """error_id""") > 0 Or json = "" Then 'check for error
        MsgBox "There was a problem." & vbLf & vbLf & json, vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    json = Mid(json, InStr(json, "[{""") + 3) 'tidy response with string functions
    json = Left(json, InStr(json, "}],") - 1)
    json = Replace(Replace(Replace(json, Chr(34), ""), ",", vbNewLine), "_", " ")
    json = Replace(StrConv(Replace(json, ":", " :" & vbTab & vbTab _
            & vbTab), vbProperCase), " Per ", "/")

    MsgBox json, vbInformation, "Site Statistics" 'display response
End Sub
```

Note how the extraction for a simple response like this can be managed with basic [string functions](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-string-functions/).

---

## Extract values with basic String functions

As another example, using the JSON data at the top of your question, if the string was in a variable called `json` and you wanted to extract the value for `bestBuy`, one way (of several possible methods) would be like this:

```
Sub jsonExtract_Demo()
    Const json = "aaaaaaa""bestBuy"": ""6.04"",."           'for demo

    Dim pStart As Long, pStop As Long, bestBuy As Single
    Dim prefix As String, suffix As String
    prefix = "bestBuy"": """                                'equivalent to:   "bestBuy": "
    suffix = """"                                           'equivalent to a single   "

    pStart = InStr(json, prefix) + Len(prefix)              'find beginning of value
    pStop = InStr(pStart, json, suffix)                     'find end of value
    bestBuy = CSng(Mid(json, pStart, pStop - pStart))       'extract & convert value
    MsgBox "The value for 'bestBuy` is : " & bestBuy, vbInformation
End Sub
```

---

## `WEBSERVICE` Worksheet Function

Last thing I wanted to point out is an often overlooked Excel worksheet function that works fine for most plain-text responses (such as this [JSON example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bahamas10/css-color-names/master/css-color-names.json)):

Enter in a **worksheet cell**:

```
=WEBSERVICE("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bahamas10/css-color-names/master/css-color-names.json")
```

...and you'll be instantly presented with the raw text result, ready to manipulate with worksheet functions as necessary.  In the case of [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) responses, [`WEBSERVICE`](https://support.office.com/article/webservice-function-0546a35a-ecc6-4739-aed7-c0b7ce1562c4) can be combined with [`FILTERXML`](https://support.office.com/article/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7) to extract specific pieces of data using [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp), which can be very handy for basic scraping needs.

*Further information in the links included above.*

Comment: They are extracting the JSON string from the responseText. It's easier to find if you Ctrl + F with "data":[  as search term. +1

Comment: @QHarr and ashleedawg Thank you So much!